macOS: getting AVAudioFile readIntoBuffer: progression
On MacOS, in Objective-C, I need to read an audio file to convert it in WAV.Reading of the file is made in creating an AVAudioFile then apply the readIntoBuffer: method to it, in order to fill an AVAudioPCMBuffer.
As the readIntoBuffer: method can take some time for big audio files (for instance about 25 seconds for a 4-hour file on a M1 Max Mac Studio), I would like to display a progress bar to inform the user of the state of this reading operation. I cannot find any property to query from a NSTimer firing block, neither on the AVAudioFile instance nor on the AVAudioPCMBuffer instance.
Any idea of a mean to get information about the bytes or frames read while the buffer is ongoing filling? Thanks!

Read the file in small chunks, then your progress chunksRead / totalChunks.

I did, using AVAssetReader, but unfortunately, some users experienced a problem, probably due to a MacOS bug (as told by the dev support team), so the working solution I found is to read in a buffer using AVAudioFile readIntoBuffer: method to fill it, but with no access to the progression of this operation

You mean reading a small chunk of a large file can take 25 seconds?

No no, total time for the file itself.

Try reading the file in small chunks using AVAudioFile

Yes, Thanks. I did that last night, cutting in multiple buffers then merging those in one. It works on my devices, awaiting news from a client who had trouble with my former method (using AVAssetReader/Writer. The Apple dev support replied to my that it is probably a system or framework bug)

The AVAssetReader/Writer approach sounds interesting. You should post that as a separate question.
